# Pygame not identifying collisions

Tags: python, pygame

but Im new to pygame and still working out the little quirks. I have the collide function not throwing anymore errors at me but it cant detect the collisions? I know that it compares the top left points so does that mean that the sprites would have to have the same size?
I resized my objects to be the same size but it wouldn't pick up on it,  but I know that there is definetly a way to get it moving. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

```
from classyforryan import sprites
import pygame
import os
import time

pygame.init() #short for initialize does return a tuple of successful intilizaton
gameDisplay= pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

bg=pygame.image.load('clouds_converted.jpg')
moore=pygame.image.load("baemoore_converted.png")
jump = False
fall = False

cube = pygame.image.load("otherreferece.png")
player=sprites(moore, 50, 544)
ob = sprites(cube, 2125, 540) #changing 580 to 540
ob1 = sprites(cube, 2125, 540)
ob2 = sprites(cube, 2125, 540)


clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class sprite1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, ob, ob1, ob2):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        #self.image = pygame.image.load("1136693.jpg")
        self.spritesgroup = pygame.sprite.Group() #sprite group
        self.spritesgroup.add(ob)
        self.spritesgroup.add(ob1)
        self.spritesgroup.add(ob2)
        #self.spritesgroup = pygame.sprite.Group() #sprite group
        pygame.display.update()



while not gameExit:
    clock.tick(40)
    timer = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit=True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if not fall:
                    jump = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                gameExit= True
    if jump:
        player.recty -= 18
        if player.recty <= 410:
            ycoor = 500
            jump = False
            fall = True

    if fall:
        player.recty += 18
        if player.recty >= 544:
            ycoor = 0
            fall = False
    pygame.display.update()
    gameDisplay.blit(bg,[0,0])
    time.sleep(.05)
    player.pos()
    ob.pos()
    ob.left()
    ob1.pos()
    ob2.pos()
    if(timer > 1600):
        ob1.left()
    if(timer > 2800):
        ob2.left()  
    score = 100
    spritegroup=sprite1(ob, ob1, ob2)
    blocks_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, spritegroup.spritesgroup, True)

    print(blocks_hit_list)
    #for block in blocks_hit_list:
    #    score +=1
    #    print("yo new score is", score)
pygame.quit() #unintiliazes pygames
quit() #this will exit out of python
```

and here are my classes that I import

```
import pygame
import os
import time

gameDisplay= pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
class sprites(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, xcoor, ycoor):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rectx=xcoor
        self.recty=ycoor
        self.rect.topleft = self.rectx, self.recty
    def pos(self):
        gameDisplay.blit(self.image, [self.rectx, self.recty])
    def left(self):
        dist = 7
        self.rectx = self.rectx - dist
```

Comment: You should look up a tutorial on pygame. As of right now there are things in your code that are a bit strange. Your `sprite1` class seems completely unnecessary. If a class only holds one attribute and the `__init__` method it most likely shouldn't be a class. `pygame.display.update()` should only be called once each game loop and you could use the sprite group to update and draw your sprites. I recommend [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMt47wvK6u0&t=5126s&list=PL4Yp6gRH-R1Birdm-Gs-SdBFWLUC1q3Fa&index=4) talk. He goes over pygame in good detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pygame.sprite.collide()` use the sprites' `rect` attribute to check if a collision has happen. You're creating a rect object for every sprite but are using another attribute to move and position them. The `self.rect` attribute is at the same position throughout the game. So the player and the objects will never collide unless they start at the same position, and then they'll always collide.

Instead of creating new attributes `self.rectx` and `self.recty`, use your rect's x and y to move the sprite. This can be accessed by dot-notation.

```
class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):  # Start classnames with capital letter!
    def __init__(self, image, x_coor, y_coor):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__()
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x_coor  # Notice that we're assigning to the rects x value!
        self.rect.y = y_coor  # The same here.

    def pos(self):
        gameDisplay.blit(self.image, self.rect)  # Position the sprite according to the the rect.

    def left(self):
        dist = 7
        self.rect.x = self.rect.x - dist  # Assigning to the rect's x attribute.
```

In the rest of your program you should change the attributes `player.rect.x` and `player.rect.y` instead of `player.rectx` and `player.recty`.